# Firefox: Multiple borders with border-radius set, overlayed on top of each other, show ragged edges

Tags: css, firefox

**The HTML**

```
<div id='loader'>
    <div id='loaderLargeSlice' class='loaderSlice'>
        <div class='arc'></div>
        <div class='arc'></div>
        <div class='arc'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#loader{    
    position: relative;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    margin: 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: none;
}

.loaderSlice
{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;

    opacity: 0.5;
}

#loaderLargeSlice
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    animation: spin 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

.arc
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    left: -14px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: 14px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.arc + .arc
{
    transform: rotate(70deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
}

.arc + .arc + .arc
{    
    transform: rotate(140deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
}
```

**The Problem**

Firefox shows ragged edges

[image: Firefox shows ragged edges]

Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: I dont have FF here, but can you try using `box-sizing:border-box;` to see if with that property set you have the same issue?

Comment: Didn't seem to help :(

Comment: looks like this is just a quirk of Gecko rendering atm, and i'm not aware of a fix.  filed a bug if you want to cc yourself: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering as unfixable. See @Eevee's comment on the main post.